# Cannot access terminal in recovery mode on M1 Mac

Tags: macos, big-sur, recovery, apple-silicon, sip

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://techstuffer.com/disable-sip-apple-silicon-m1/) to temporaily disable SIP on my new M1 MacBook Air.

Once I get into recovery mode, instead of seeing a Utilities menu where I can open the terminal, I see a message that says "There are no users on this volume to recover" (image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN5ta.jpg)) and all I can do from here is restart the computer.

What do I need to do so that I'm prompted to enter my administrator password and access the terminal in recovery mode?

Comment: Have you created a user yet?

Comment: Yes - I have a user from when I setup the Mac that I can log in to MacOS with (e.g. when not booting into recovery mode)

Comment: If you do not find an answer to this issue, then consider filling a bug report to **Apple**: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

Comment: This is going to be an XY question - what is one thing you want to do once SIP is disabled? (Or is this just to prove you can do it, the goal is understanding the new boot process?)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue on my Mac Mini M1. To solve it, I had to restore the Mac Mini using Apple Configurator 2. Please have a look here to learn how to do that: https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-2/revive-or-restore-a-mac-with-apple-silicon-apdd5f3c75ad/mac

Comment: Did you revive or restore @gabriele?

Comment: After using the revive command, with no success, I restored the Mac Mini. I should note that the Mac Mini with which I had that issue was brand new. I received it three days ago. While installing software called Loopback, which needs to apply a specific setting using the recovery mode, I discovered that the recovery mode was not working properly. So I had to restore it and reinstall everything again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you’re not actually in recovery mode if it’s trying to reset a password or no user qualifies to unlock the storage. I would start up back to macOS and be sure you have internet, wired Ethernet preferably, and try to validate your user is set up properly or make a new admin account. Then I would do all updates and reboot.

Just about [everything you learned on Intel](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) needs to [take a back seat for Apple Silicon machines](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/14/m1-macs-radically-change-boot-and-recovery/).

If you [press and hold the power button](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&q=m1%20boot%20to%20recovery&requestid=&product=&currentPage=1&locale=en_US&includeArchived=false&doctype=&supportAnswerIndex=2), are you seeing options?

> **Apple silicon**
> Turn on your Mac and continue to press and hold the power button until you see the startup options window. Click the gear icon labeled Options, then click Continue.

In your case, if there are no users that are properly entangled with the controller chip Secure Enclave to unlock the encrypted drive, you may have to fix that in macOS or backup and restore the Mac using Apple Configurator.

Also, you may want or need to get to 11.4.1 and ensure you have what Howard Oakley called 1TR configured:

- https://eclecticlight.co/2021/06/03/launching-recovery-on-an-m1-mac-booting-and-control-in-11-4/

This is a very complicated situation and we will probably need to know exact versions of macOS, recoveryOS, what security mode you are running in, if you have MDM, DEP, and recreate the path your Mac came into existence.

***Reality is way more complicated than SIP or noSIP now.***

It might be far easier to wipe it entirely and get things running and patched now in June 2021 updates and improvements Apple has shipped. Initially all the tooling you needed didn’t ship.